# How To Send file from iPhone to another iPhone using node.js and socket.io?

Tags: ios, node.js, socket.io

How To Send file from iPhone to another iPhone  using node.js and socket.io. Which package i have to use and should i have to write script on client side i.e. iPhone if yes how it will run on iPhone side .

Answer (score 1):

http://socket.io :socket package for node. You dont even need to write the script on your own for the client side completely for making connection with the node server, as they provide you with the js file for doing that.

> How to run on iphone?

http://docs.phonegap.com.
If you are building an app for iphone you would like to put your javascript code inside the phonegap app and your code will run on iphone in web view, like in any web browser

Answer (score 1):

I created a swift socketio client: [SocketIOCocoa](https://github.com/shuoli84/SocketIOCocoa). Hope it helps.